# Unable to locate element: Gmail email ID

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gmail

Trying to locate the id for the gmail username to send a key to. When using the code below, python keeps returning that it cannot locate the element.

`chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")`

The HTML is:

`<input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" value="" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">`

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Recently I use this for automate gmail login:

```
username = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "input[placeholder='Username']")
password = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "input[placeholder='Password']")
login_button = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "button.src-components-Login-LoginPanel-LoginForm-index__submit--2fvkB ")
username.send_keys(user)
password.send_keys(pwd)
login_button.click()
```

Hope this helps!